# using namespace std and library

Tags: c++

Why we need both the "header file" and the `using namespace` tag for the any library function to get executed properly. For example `cout` will not work unless we use `iostream`. Also it will not work unless we use "using namespace std". My question is why do we need combination of both `using namespace std` as well as `#include <iostream>` for `cout` to execute successfully?

Comment: When I started c++, I was wondering this too.

Comment: You really don't "need" `using namespace std;`. In fact, you're better off not using it in most situations. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: what I asked basically was why to use "using namespace std" or in your case " std::cout " when we had already added iostream. I did not ask for which one is better " using namespace std" or the std::cout .Anyways Thanks.

Comment: And the link tells you the there is no "why". It is a bad idea so you should avoid it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Including a library header makes the library feature visible to your program code. Without that, your program has no idea that the library even exists. This is the part that is necessary.

Writing `using namespace std` simply allows you to write `cout` rather than the full name which is `std::cout`. It's a convenience, that's all.

Answer (score 4):

`cout` is defined in the `std` namespace, and you can use it without adding a `using namespace` like

```
std::cout << "Hello, World" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my question is why do we need it in the first place. Since once we exposed "iostream" then why can't we simply use cout. Why to use std::cout or using namespace std.

Comment: Namespaces were added to the language. They allow you to reduce and or eliminate variable name collisions. What if you wrote your own class named string? Or a variable named cin?

Answer (score 3):

> Thanks for the reply. But my question is why do we need it in the first place.
>   Since once we exposed "iostream" then why can't we simply use cout.
>
> Why to use std::cout or using namespace std?

When you don't use the std namespace, compiler will try to call cout or cin as if it weren't defined in a namespace. Since it doesn't exist there, compiler  tries to call something that doesn't exist! Hence, an error occurs.

Comment: I understood the concept now. Thank You so much!